# How to connect MS SQL Server database from ASP.NET Core 2.2 hosted in **1&1 Ionos** hosting server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, angular7, web-hosting, asp.net-core-2.2

I am developing a web application with asp.net core 2.2 and angular 7. My application is working locally but when I upload the application and SQL Server database to **"1&1 Ionos"** hosting server, it can't connect to the database there.

I tried with the connection string they provided in their database admin panel but it just not working.

Here is the appsettings I used in my application.

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Secret": "bla bla bla"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CustomPosConnection": "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=db784146660.hosting-data.io,1433;Initial Catalog=myDbName;User Id=myUserId;Password=myPass;"
  }
}
```

Here **"myDb"** ,**"myUserId"**,**"myPass"** is equivalent to actual database name ,actual user id they provided and actual password that i set when creating database in the hosting server.

Please help me to connect the database in **1&1 ionos** hosting server by suggesting write connection string or guiding me what else I need to do or please share if anyone has example connection string for connecting to SQL Server  database from **asp.net mvc** or **asp.net web api** or **asp.net core** application hosted in **1&1 Ionos** windows server.

Comment: you should write your servername or IP address for `Data Source` value, you dont need write sql port in connectionstring. This is an example: `"Data Source=192.168.5.17;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=false;UId=sa;pwd=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`

Comment: Why don't you try asking their support rather?

Comment: Do not use Integrated Security = false.  It probably won't work.  Use Integrated Security = true and eliminate the user name and password.  The SQL Server defaults to using Windows credentials (true) which uses the users windows account.  Normally I create a Windows Group Account and set the database to use the group account.  Then add uses to Group so multiple uses have access to the database.  In a corporate network that uses Group Policy the group accounts already exist.

Answer (score 1):

At last it worked,here is my working appsettings. Hopefully it will help you guys.

```
  "AppSettings": {
    "Secret": "bla bla bla"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CustomPosConnection": "Data Source=db784146660.hosting-data.io,1433;Initial Catalog=myDb;Integrated Security=False;User Id=myUserId;Password=myPass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
}
```

Here **"myDb"** ,**"myUserId"**,**"myPass"** is equivalent to actual database name ,actual user id they provided and actual password that i set when creating database in the hosting server.

Comment: It won't help because it's not clear how this differs from the question's connection string. You *don't* need to add `Integrated Security=False;`, that's false by default. The only real difference seems to be `MARS=True`, but even that won't *prevent* you from connecting. 1433 is the default port so there's no need to specify it either

Comment: it just worked for me that's why i thought to share it.

Comment: *What* worked? The only meaningful change seems to be removing the meaningless `Provider=sqloledb;`. This would be needed if you used OledbConnection but not SqlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

It has been hard to figure out the connection string for .Net core shared hosting. My provider AspHostPortal worded with

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=ipAddress\\SQL2017,782; Database=DatabaseFileName_without.mdf;Integrated Security=False; User Id=userName;Pwd=passWord;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Integrated Security=True may not work if SSL is not enabled on server

I am not sure why Microsoft change the format from Web.Config format to confuse everybody.